# C170 Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, webcam

I've just purchased a C170 from logitech, and on my 2 pcs running Ubuntu 12 and 13, the system will not recognise that the cam is plugged in.  When I plug in, the green light switches on for 10 seconds then switches off, and will not work at all (Cam apps hang if I try to use them) except in SKYPE, where I have no problem whatsoever!!!

```
Getting the following in the terminal with LSUSB:
downes@downes-Latitude-D620:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:a005 Dell Computer Corp. Internal 2.0 Hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0b97:7762 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 SmartCard Reader
downes@downes-Latitude-D620:~$
```

Help please....  Any ideas willingly received!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is my experience running Ubuntu 13:10 and the Logitech C170, ymmv.

I have been a distro hopper and dabbler off and on for years, so, though I'm by no means a guru, I'm not new to Linux or ubuntu or .deb based systems, either.

When I hooked up my C170, it wouldn't work in Skype. Surfing the net, I found a suggestion to try seeing if it would get recognized as a media streaming device in VLC.

While talking with my daughter on Skype and FB video chat and netrunner (an Ubuntu offshoot O/S), I tried doing this (using VLC) and hooking the C170 into a usb hub. I got it to work instantly (Skype) for the video. The audio, not so much.

I was going to test the new (to me) Ubuntu 13:10 anyway. So, I installed that. It did recognize the C170 as 'being there' but, again, did not work, neither video nor audio, in Skype.

So, I did the VLC streaming again and still got that working. I checked the sound in System Settings and was able to choose the C170 and got the sound working. I'm unsure at this point if I have to have VLC running or not, to get the video working (since my daughter or anyone else I'd call is asleep right now) but I will test that as well.

I got this with `lsusb`:

```
gypsygrrl@gypsygrrl-OptiPlex-GX520:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:01a4 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Wireless Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 050d:945a Belkin Components F7D1101 v1 Basic Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

So, try running an instance of VLC and then, leave it running, and test your camera that way.